# how to fix an error when calling a method?

Tags: java

I have to call the method that takes an array list of parameter and moves the minimum value in front of the list. I keep getting an error int this line:

```
System.out.printf("Display numbers\n", myList.minInteger);
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinToFront{

    public static void main (String [] args){


    MinToFront myList = new MinToFront();

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(92);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(17);
    list.add(9);
    myList.minToFront(list);
    System.out.printf("Display numbers\n", myList.minInteger);

   }// end of main


public static void minToFront (ArrayList<Integer> minInteger){
int result = 0;
int min = minInteger.get(0);
for (int i = 0; i < minInteger.size(); i++){
if (minInteger.get(i)< min) {
min = minInteger.get(i);
result = min;
}
}
minInteger.add(0, minInteger.remove(result));

 }// end of method

}//end of class
```

Comment: Most methods require parameters, so you might try myList.minInteger() instead of myList.minInteger   There are most likely many other errors, but that's the one that jumps out at me for that line.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What error are you getting? Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, writing "Display numbers" does not display numbers. It displays the sentence you just wrote. Second, do not create an instance if the class includes `main()`.

Lastly, you should put brackets at the end of a method while calling it.

Here is your code, corrected:

```
public static void minToFront (ArrayList<Integer> minInteger)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int min = minInteger.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < minInteger.size(); i++)
        {
            if (minInteger.get(i)< min)
            {
                min = minInteger.get(i);
                result = min;
            }
        }
        minInteger.add(0, result);
        minInteger.remove(result);
    }// end of method

}//end of class
```

Comment: public static void minToFront(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
             int min = 0;
             for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                 if (list.get(i) < list.get(min)) {
                     min = i;
                 }
             }
             int oldValue = list.remove(min);
      list.add(0, oldValue);
        }